Server and client not communicating when running them on separate scenes
I'm programming a chess-like war game on Godot 4.2.1. I'm currently programming the multiplayer functionality so that I could start coding the game logic (it would be hard to code the logic if you can't test it). Currently, the networking works if I run two instances of either game_red or game_blue, but it doesn't work if I run both game_red and game_blue simultaneously. Why is that? I don't understand.
The problem has to be in networking.gd (singleton) or messages.gd.
Here's the project: https://github.com/mankki/WarGame.git
PS. All critique on the code is warmly welcome.

Firstly I'd recommend better organising your project into relevant folders. Secondly it would be tedious and time consuming for someone else to isolate the problem in your entire project so try to log/print what is happening at each step and isolate the problem at it's root cause and then maybe try making a Minimal reproducible example

Thanks for the tips! I ultimately decided to go with just one client script and scene, so that solved the problem.
